# A combinatorics problem from the IMO 1982

Tags: combinatorics

I was doing some old International Mathematical Olympiad (IMO) problems and one question went this way:

> In a party with 1982 persons, among any group of 4, there is at least one person, who knows each of other three. What is the minimum number of people in the party who knows everyone else?

My knowledge of combinatorics is not working here. I'm stuck and completely  blank, hope you guys can help me with it (You can use advance combinatorics but in a simple manner). Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1982_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1) Aops post could help.

Comment: This was an USAMO question to be precise.

Comment: I was there at IMO '82, but this problem doesn't ring a bell. Are you sure? Ahh, it was USAMO '82. Ok.

Comment: it is possible that you are right, but it is mentioned in my book that it is IMO 1982 problem.Anyway that is not the matter.

Comment: I wonder what the answer would be if the question is changed to: "In a party with $n$ persons, among any group of $k$, there is at least one person who knows each of other $k-1$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Show by induction for $n\geq 4$ that in a party with $n$ people, there are at least $(n-3)$ people who know everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ does not know everyone else, say $A$ does not know $B$. Assume there is a third person $C$ who does not know everyone else.
Then for any other $X$, $X$ knows $A,B,C$. In particular, the person(s) $C$ does not know can at most be $A$ and/or $B$. By the same argument, if $X$ does not know everybody else, the persons $X$ does not know are at most among $A,B,C$ - but $X$ knows these.

Comment: You appear to use that the relation "knowing" is symmetric (notably you never consider the possibility that $B$ knows everyone). I don't think it can be inferred from the problem statement, nor do I think it is true in real life.